# Powershell to list all documents in a library

Tags: powershell

I've backed up over 200 sub sites and restored them to a new site collection with it's own content database. I want to do a quick compare of the document libraries to make sure nothing was missed.

I found the following that compares two lists, is there anything that compares two document libraries?

```
$oldReviewSite = Get-SPweb "http://portal.com/siteA"

$newReviewSite = Get-SPweb "http://portal.com/siteB"


$aList = $oldReviewSite.lists["Agenda"]
$bList = $newReviewSite.lists["Agenda"]


$arrA = @()
$arrB = @()

foreach($iA in $aList.Items)
    {
 $arrA += $iA["Title"]
}

foreach($iB in $bList.Items)
{
 $arrB += $iB["Title"]
}

$c = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $arrA -DifferenceObject $arrB -PassThru
Write-Host $c
```

I just need a simple PS script for now. I can expand it to iterate through the list of 200+ sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document libraries are derived from lists under the covers. So your example above should also work for a document library.

Take a look at this example from another question previously posted.  You can see the code is very similar:

[Traverse through List of Documents using PowerShell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3371/traverse-through-list-of-documents-using-powershell)

Comment: Thanks Erik, you were correct, I was able to list all the documents and compare them. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before but I did get it working!